# How to Exclude Mysql Group

Tags: mysql

I would like to know how to exclude a mysql group, i did research on here for some time but just dont make it right.

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM booking GROUP BY BookingId HAVING Status!="Cancellation"
```

which obviously doesn't work.

Example Database looks like this:

```
+----+-----------+--------------+
| id | BookingId | Status       |
+----+-----------+--------------+
|  1 |         1 | Booked       |
|  2 |         1 | Cancellation |
|  3 |         2 | Booked       |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

I would like to group them by BookingId and if one of the found entries got the Status Cancellation this group shouldnt show up, so from above just the id 3 would be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use aggregate functions like `sum` in a having clause

```
SELECT BookingId  
FROM booking 
GROUP BY BookingId 
HAVING sum(Status = 'Cancellation') = 0
```